# Mandar datos desde BroadcastReceiver a activiy principal sin intenciones

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Que tal soy nuevo, tengo el siguiente problema en android studio.
Deseo identificar un numero de llamada entrante que se visualice en la actividad principal, estoy  usando BroadcastReceiver para detectar el numero entrante. 
Codigo donde uso BroadcastReceiver que es en la clase llamadaentrante:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        String numeroentrante = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        numero=numeroentrante;
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("MI_ESPECIFICA_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("numero", numero);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }
    else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        //Toast.makeText(context, "LLamada detenida",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

Muestro el Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="MI_ESPECIFICA_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".util.LlamadEntrante">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

En el siguiente código muestro como recibe el dato en la actividad principal.

```
BroadcastReceiver miReceptor;
IntentFilter intentFilter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
miReceptor=new MiBroadCastReceiver();
    intentFilter=new IntentFilter("MI_ESPECIFICA_ACTION");
}


@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(miReceptor,intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(miReceptor);
}

public class MiBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i){


        String dato1= i.getExtras().getString("numero");
        if (dato1 != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"numero entrante " + dato1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (btSocket!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write("led2".toString().getBytes());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    msg("Error");
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Gracias todo quedo resuelto, ahora puedo aprovechar este dato en la actividad principal... código corregido.

Comment: Es incorrecto, sendbroadcast envia un mensaje al framework de Android para que sea recibido por cualquier reciever configurado para hacerlo. No queda claro que quieres hacer con ese dato, adonde lo quieres enviar? quieres abrir un activity nuevo o no?

Comment: El dato la quiero mostrar simplemente en un textView en la activity principal, pero sin que la activity se inicie, lo cual sucede con las Intent. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver quedo de esta manera: